# VS Code debugger for rails docker: Breakpoints are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker-compose, vscode-debugger, ruby-debug-ide

I have installed the Ruby plugin in VS Code and the following gems in docker and configured 3000 and 1234 ports.

**Gems**:

```
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
```

**Command**:

`bundle exec rdebug-ide --debug --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- bin/rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0`

**Launch.json**: I have tried all possible configurations I found online and was able to connect the debugger with many but I could never catch the breakpoints in VS Code.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": "Rails Docker Debug",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "attach",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteHost": "localhost",
        "remotePort": "1234",
        "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": "Rails Docker Debug",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "attach",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/foldername",
        "remoteHost": "localhost",
        "remotePort": "1234",
        "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/foldername",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried many combinations of folder names but I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).